# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?

Tags: .htaccess, http, cors, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

Is there a way to allow multiple cross-domains using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

I'm aware of the `*`, but it is too open. I really want to allow just a couple domains.

As an example, something like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain1.example, http://domain2.example
```

I have tried the above code but it does not seem to work in Firefox.

Is it possible to specify multiple domains or am I stuck with just one?

Comment: [Rather than allowing a space-separated list of origins, (origin-list-or-null) is either a single origin or the string "null".](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header) (thanks @maxpolk)

Comment: Using the most recent Firefox, neither comma seperated, nor space seperated domains did work. Matching against a list of domains and putting a single host in the headers is still better security and does work properly.

Comment: If you're struggling with this for HTTPS, I found a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains/28552592#28552592).

Comment: @sam or "*" ? `shared based by returning the value of the Origin request header, "*", or "null"`

Comment: **_important note_**: allowing only cretain domains in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header does **not** mean that other domains cannot trigger a method on this endpoint (e.g. REST API method). It just means that disallowed origins cannot use the result in javascript (browser ensures this). For restricting access to an endpoint for specific domains use a server-side request filter that e.g. returns HTTP 401 for disallowed domains.

Comment: You should always append `Vary: Origin` header when you want to use multiple URLs, see: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-http-caches

Answer (score 1060, accepted):

Sounds like the recommended way to do it is to have your server read the Origin header from the client, compare that to the list of domains you would like to allow, and if it matches, echo the value of the `Origin` header back to the client as the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response.

With `.htaccess` you can do it like this:

```xml
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Allow loading of external fonts
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(google.com|staging.google.com|development.google.com|otherdomain.example|dev02.otherdomain.example)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
        Header merge Vary Origin
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: How would you add wildcard subdomains like: `*.example.com` or wildcard ports like: `localhost:*`

Comment: For anyone wondering you can do `(.+\.google.com)` instead of `(google.com|staging.google.com)`

Comment: How would this behave if there is no match? Which would be the output of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`?

Comment: That regex is not well designed; in particular, insecure origins (using the `http` scheme) shouldn't be allowed, and DNS label separators should be escaped (`\.` instead of `.`); otherwise, an attacker could for instance buy the `developmentzgoogle.com` domain and mount cross-origin attacks from there.

Comment: @Héctor In such case it will just behave like this solution wasn't introduced at all - just will block all requests from non-matching domains.

Answer (score 285):

Another solution I'm using in PHP:

```
$http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];

if ($http_origin == "http://www.domain1.com" || $http_origin == "http://www.domain2.com" || $http_origin == "http://www.domain3.com")
{  
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin");
}
```

Comment: HTTP_ORIGIN  is not reliable,  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231116/serverhttp-origin-doesnt-work

Comment: @bareMetal your comment is only partially correct. While it is true that there are cases where the  [`Origin` HTTP header is `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76180946/3673659), it is also important to note that this header is utilized in the default CORS mechanism for allowing or disallowing requests. The implementation mentioned here ensures strict matching (==) of specified origins and disallows requests when there is no match (i.e., `null` is considered a non-match). This approach is considered a safe implementation.

Comment: There is a far worse issue with HTTP_ORIGIN. It can be easily spoofed and thus a PHP programmer can send a request to your website and pretend that the ORIGIN is coming from a trusted URL.

Answer (score 134):

This worked for me:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(domain\.example|domain2\.example)$" origin_is=$0 
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
```

When put in `.htaccess`, it will work for sure.

Answer (score 97):

I had the same problem with woff-fonts, multiple subdomains had to have access. To allow subdomains I added something like this to my httpd.conf:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.example\.com)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
<FilesMatch "\.woff$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e" env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN
</FilesMatch>
```

For multiple domains you could just change the regex in `SetEnvIf`.

Comment: Handy to have an example for multiple domains: `^(https?:\/\/localhost:\d+)$|^(https?:\/\/.+\.yourdomain\.com)$` Here's it in action... https://regex101.com/r/GZHTLB/1 It's crazy gobbledegook but that regex101 site helps decipher it all.

Answer (score 78):

Here's how to echo the Origin header back if it matches your domain with Nginx, this is useful if you want to serve a font multiple sub-domains:

```
location /fonts {
    # this will echo back the origin header
    if ($http_origin ~ "example.org$") {
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" $http_origin;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 61):

For ExpressJS applications you can use:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const corsWhitelist = [
        'https://domain1.example',
        'https://domain2.example',
        'https://domain3.example'
    ];
    if (corsWhitelist.indexOf(req.headers.origin) !== -1) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    }

    next();
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I had it almost right :) You can now simplify to `corsWhiteList.includes(req.headers.origin)`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors-w-dynamic-origin

Answer (score 38):

Here is what i did for a PHP application which is being requested by AJAX

```
$request_headers        = apache_request_headers();
$http_origin            = $request_headers['Origin'];
$allowed_http_origins   = array(
                            "http://myDumbDomain.example"   ,
                            "http://anotherDumbDomain.example"  ,
                            "http://localhost"  ,
                          );
if (in_array($http_origin, $allowed_http_origins)){  
    @header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $http_origin);
}
```

If the requesting origin is allowed by my server, return the `$http_origin` itself as value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header instead of returning a `*` wildcard.

Comment: Should probably check that `$request_headers['Origin'];` exists, otherwise any direct requests are going to trigger an E_NOTICE.

Answer (score 27):

As mentioned above, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should be unique and `Vary` should be set to `Origin` if you are behind a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

Relevant part of my Nginx configuration:

```bash
if ($http_origin ~* (https?://.*\.mydomain\.com(:[0-9]+)?)) {
  set $cors "true";
}
if ($http_origin ~* (https?://.*\.my-other-domain\.com(:[0-9]+)?)) {
  set $cors "true";
}

if ($cors = "true") {
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
  add_header 'X-Frame-Options' "ALLOW FROM $http_origin";
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
  add_header 'Vary' 'Origin';
}
```

Comment: any `.` in the domain needs to be escaped, otherwise it matches any character. Also, you can have just one if statement instead of using a variable

Answer (score 25):

There is one disadvantage you should be aware of: As soon as you out-source files to a CDN (or any other server which doesn't allow scripting) or if your files are cached on a proxy, altering response based on 'Origin' request header will not work.

Answer (score 25):

For Nginx users to allow CORS for multiple domains. I like the @marshall's example although his anwers only matches one domain. To match a list of domain and subdomain this regex make it ease to work with fonts:

```
location ~* \.(?:ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
   if ( $http_origin ~* (https?://(.+\.)?(domain1|domain2|domain3)\.(?:me|co|com)$) ) {
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "$http_origin";
   }
}
```

This will only echo "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" headers that matches with the given list of domains.

Comment: Be warned: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Answer (score 24):

For multiple domains, in your `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(domain1.example|domain2.example)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Great. Helped me.

Answer (score 16):

For IIS 7.5+ with URL Rewrite 2.0 module installed please see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31084417/1246870)

Answer (score 16):

Here's a solution for Java web app, based the answer from yesthatguy.

I am using Jersey REST 1.x

Configure the web.xml to be aware of Jersey REST and the CORSResponseFilter

```xml
<!-- Jersey REST config -->
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>com.your.package.CORSResponseFilter</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.your.package</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here's the code for CORSResponseFilter

```java
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;


public class CORSResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter{

    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request,
            ContainerResponse response) {
        
        String[] allowDomain = {"http://localhost:9000","https://my.domain.example"};
        Set<String> allowedOrigins = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList (allowDomain));                  
        
        String originHeader = request.getHeaderValue("Origin");
        
        if(allowedOrigins.contains(originHeader)) {
            response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", originHeader);
                        
            response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
            response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        }
        
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Maybe I am wrong, but as far as I can see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` has an `"origin-list"` as parameter.

By [definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header) an `origin-list` is:

```
origin            = "origin" ":" 1*WSP [ "null" / origin-list ]
origin-list       = serialized-origin *( 1*WSP serialized-origin )
serialized-origin = scheme "://" host [ ":" port ]
                  ; <scheme>, <host>, <port> productions from RFC3986
```

And from this, I argue different origins are admitted and should be **space separated**.

Comment: Looks like the spec has changed: @drAlberT's 'definition' link above has the following definitions: `wildcard = "*"` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin = origin-or-null / wildcard`. The answer is from 2012; checking back in the GitHub repo referenced in the document, this definition goes back to at least June 2014. In fact @drAlberT's link just takes you to the top of the document (presumably the location id has been removed/changed), go straight to the relevant place with [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#http-new-header-syntax) (a www.w3.org link but forwards you to fetch.spec.whatwg.org)

Comment: further to my other comment, same `origin-or-null / wildcard` definition also found [on mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 9):

PHP Code:

```php
$httpOrigin = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] : null;
if (in_array($httpOrigin, [
    'http://localhost:9000', // Co-worker dev-server
    'http://127.0.0.1:9001', // My dev-server
])) header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ${httpOrigin}");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

Comment: DO not use this in production, its not safe.

Answer (score 8):

I struggled to set this up for a domain running HTTPS, so I figured I would share the solution. I used the following directive in my *httpd.conf* file:

```
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
            SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?example\.com$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    </FilesMatch>
```

Change `example.com` to your domain name.  Add this inside `<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:xx>` in your *httpd.conf* file.  Notice that if your `VirtualHost` has a port suffix (e.g. `:80`) then this directive will not apply to HTTPS, so you will need to also go to */etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl* and add the same directive in that file, inside of the `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` section.

Once the config files are updated, you will need to run the following commands in the terminal:

```
a2enmod headers
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: I like this option and combined/modified it with the implementation that  @George has. Sometimes servers don't have a2enmod available, so all you have to do is check your main httpd.conf to see if the line: LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so is uncommented.

Comment: My origin had a port number, so I modified the regular expression to include that:  `^http(s)?://(.+\.)?example\.com(:\d+)?$`

Answer (score 7):

If you are having trouble with fonts, use:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 3):

HTTP_ORIGIN is not used by all browsers.  [How secure is HTTP_ORIGIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566378/how-secure-http-origin-is) For me it comes up empty in FF.
I have the sites that I allow access to my site send over a site ID, I then check my DB for the record with that id and get the SITE_URL column value (www.yoursite.com).

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://'.$row['SITE_URL']);
```

Even if the send over a valid site ID the request needs to be from the domain listed in my DB associated with that site ID.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an expanded option for apache that includes some of the latest and planned font definitions:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2|sfnt|svg)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(domainname1|domainname2|domainname3)\.(?:com|net|org)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1$2
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 3):

For a fairly easy copy / paste for .NET applications, I wrote this to enable CORS from within a `global.asax` file.  This code follows the advice given in the currently accepted answer, reflecting whatever origin back is given in the request into the response.  This effectively achieves '*' without using it.

**The reason for this is that it enables multiple other CORS features**, including the ability to send an AJAX XMLHttpRequest with the 'withCredentials' attribute set to 'true'.

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        Response.End();
    }
    else
    {
        Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        if (Request.Headers["Origin"] != null)
            Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" , Request.Headers["Origin"]);
        else
            Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" , "*");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP code example for matching subdomains.

```
if( preg_match("/http:\/\/(.*?)\.yourdomain.example/", $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $matches )) {
        $theMatch = $matches[0];
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $theMatch);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To facilitate multiple domain access for an ASMX service, I created this function in the global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CORSServices = "/account.asmx|/account2.asmx";
    if (CORSServices.IndexOf(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath) > -1)
    {
        string allowedDomains = "http://xxx.yyy.example|http://aaa.bbb.example";

        if(allowedDomains.IndexOf(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Origin"]) > -1)
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Origin"]);

        if(HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

This allows for CORS handling of `OPTIONS` verb also.

Answer (score 1):

Google's support answer on [serving ads over SSL](https://support.google.com/adxbuyer/answer/3202326?hl=en) and the [grammar in the RFC itself](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-7.1) would seem to indicate that you can space delimit the URLs. Not sure how well-supported this is in different browsers.

Comment: 'serving ads over ssl' links to the spec http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header which adds a note, "In practice the origin-list-or-null production is more constrained. Rather than allowing a space-separated list of origins, it is either a single origin or the string "null".

Comment: While it's important to note that detail, when a specification says "In practice", it doesn't mean that it's only valid to do it that way. It means that if you do it that way, you may run into problems because the majority of implementors either implement the spec incorrectly or incompletely. The specification does allow for a space-separated list of origins, which you can see here in the EBNF under `origin-list`: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6454#section-7.1

Answer (score 1):

And one more answer in Django. To have a single view allow CORS from multiple domains, here is my code:

```python
def my_view(request):
    if 'HTTP_ORIGIN' in request.META.keys() and request.META['HTTP_ORIGIN'] in ['http://allowed-unsecure-domain.com', 'https://allowed-secure-domain.com', ...]:
        response = my_view_response() # Create your desired response data: JsonResponse, HttpResponse...
        # Then add CORS headers for access from delivery
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = request.META['HTTP_ORIGIN']
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "GET" # "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD"
        response["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = "1000"  
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "*"  
        return response
```

Answer (score 1):

Only a single origin can be specified for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. But you can set the origin in your response according to the request. Also don't forget to set the Vary header. In PHP I would do the following:

```php
/**
 * Enable CORS for the passed origins.
 * Adds the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the response with the origin that matched the one in the request.
 * @param array $origins
 * @return string|null returns the matched origin or null
*/
function allowOrigins($origins)
{
    $val = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] ?? null;
    if (in_array($val, $origins, true)) {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$val);
        header('Vary: Origin');
        
        return $val;
    }
        
    return null;
}
    
if (allowOrigins(['http://localhost', 'https://localhost'])) {
   echo your response here, e.g. token
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution, it works well, I set the allowed origins in an array inside the functions because I have 6 origins to allow: `'capacitor://localhost', 'ionic://localhost', 'http://localhost', 'http://localhost:4200', 'http://localhost:8080', 'http://localhost:8100',`

Answer (score 1):

I have https://stackoverflow.com/a/7454204/13779574 this code worked well but gives an error when the user enters that page.
I fixed this problem with this code.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
   $http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
   if ($http_origin == "http://localhost:3000" || $http_origin == "http://api.loc/"){  
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin");
   }
}
```

Comment: DO not use this in production, its not safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you try so many code examples like me to make it work using CORS, it is worth to mention that you have to clear your cache first to try if it actually works, similiar to issues like when old images are still present, even if it's deleted on the server (because it is still saved in your cache).

For example <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + DEL</kbd> in Google Chrome to delete your cache.

This helped me using this code after trying many pure `.htaccess` solutions and this seemed the only one working (at least for me):

```
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://google.com"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "authorization, origin, user-token, x-requested-with, content-type"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(google.com|staging.google.com|development.google.com|otherdomain.com|dev02.otherdomain.net)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
            Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
        </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
```

Also note that it is widely spread that many solutions say you have to type `Header set ...` but it is `Header add ...`. Hope this helps someone having the same troubles for some hours now like me.

Answer (score 0):

Below answer is specific to C#, but the concept should be applicable to all the different platforms.

To allow Cross Origin Requests from a web api, You need to allow Option requests to your Application and Add below annotation at controller level.

[EnableCors(UrlString,Header, Method)]
Now the origins can be passed only a s string. SO if you want to pass more than one URL in the request pass it as a comma seperated value.

UrlString = "https://a.hello.com,https://b.hello.com"

Answer (score 0):

i was also facing same problem.
my client was on 9097,api gateway on 9098,microservice on ....
Actually i was using spring cloud Api gateway
in my gateway yml file i had allowed crossorigin like--
... allowedOrigins: "http://localhost:9097"

also in my microservice i was using @crossOrigin

when client sent request to api gateway, two "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" headers was coming in responce [one from api yml file and one from microservice @crossorigin]
so browser blocked request

i solved it as--

```
    @Bean
public RouteLocator getRL(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    
return  builder.routes()
    
        .route(p-> 
         "/friendlist","/guest/**"
                )
         .filters(f ->{
             //f.removeResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
             //f.addResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:9097");
             f.setResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:9097");
             return f;
         })
        .uri("lb://OLD-SERVICE")
        
        
    ).build();      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Laravel Framework** you can specify the allowed domains, for example in the CORS middleware:

`app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class Cors
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if (!method_exists($response, 'header')) {
            return $response;
        }

        $allowedOrigins = [
            'http://localhost:8000',
            'http://localhost:8080',
            'https://app.example.com',
            'https://example.com',
        ];

        if (in_array($request->header('origin'), $allowedOrigins)) {
            $origin = $request->header('origin');
        } else {
            return $response;
        }

        return $response
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization')
            ->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '86400');
    }
}
```

Or you can use an Origin request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class Cors
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if (!method_exists($response, 'header')) {
            return $response;
        }

        $origin = $request->header('origin');

        return $response
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization')
            ->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '86400');
    }
}
```

Then register it in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
```

And finally, use whatever you need on any routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'cors']], function () {
    ...
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'index']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IF Apache webserver AND security does not matter (*for example, doing tutorials on localhost or using for testing or other security-irrelevant applications*), add this to your `.htaccess` file to allow requests from any domain / origin:

```
Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

Answer (score 0):

For **SvelteKit**, add `hooks.server.ts` to `src` folder with this content:

```
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const handle: Handle = async ({ resolve, event }) => {
    const response = await resolve(event);

    const allowedOrigins = ['https://domain1.com', 'https://domain2.com'];
    console.log('allowedOrigins', allowedOrigins);

    const requestOrigin = event.request.headers.get('origin');
    console.log('requestOrigin', requestOrigin);
    

    if (allowedOrigins.includes(requestOrigin)) {
        // Handle preflight OPTIONS requests
        if (event.request.method === 'OPTIONS') {
            return new Response(null, {
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': requestOrigin,
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'
                }
            });
        }

        response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', requestOrigin);
    }

    return response;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with regex in PHP :

```php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
  $allowedReferers = [$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'localhost', 'google.com'];
  $rgx_escape = implode('|', array_map(function($value) { return preg_quote($value, '/'); }, $allowedReferers));

  if (preg_match("/$rgx_escape/", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  } else {
    http_response_code(403);
    exit;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

We can also set this in Global.asax file for Asp.net application.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    // enable CORS
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://www.youtube.com");

    }
```

Answer (score -19):

The answer seems to be to use the header more than once.  That is, rather than sending

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain1.example, http://domain2.example, http://domain3.example
```

send

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain1.example
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain2.example
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain3.example
```

On Apache, you can do this in an `httpd.conf` `<VirtualHost>` section or `.htaccess` file using `mod_headers` and this syntax:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://domain1.example"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://domain2.example"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://domain3.example"
```

The trick is to use `add` rather than `append` as the first argument.

Comment: The trick looks promising, but it doesn't work in FF 3.6.13. What I observe is that two headers with the same name are joined into one, with values separated with a comma -- and it doesn't work, as OP posted. I observed the headers in LiveHTTPHeaders and FireBug.

Comment: See, when I did it, I did "Header set ..." rather than "Header add ..." - seems to work for me. Firefox 3.6.16

Comment: This is not allowed and does not work in FF - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=671608

Comment: there's a variation on this which seems to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466496/how-to-configure-apache-to-handle-multiple-domains-with-access-control-allow-ori

Comment: Just spent two hours trying to fix an issue related to CORS and it turns out that it was because of multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers. I removed the multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers and it started working. So this is not the right answer despite the number of votes. Use this method instead to support multiple domains: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1850482/123545

Comment: You will in fact get an error message in the log from the latest Chrome browser as of now, telling you that it's ignoring the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header because there are multiple values.

Comment: Nope. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS : "A returned resource may have one Access-Control-Allow-Origin header" .. and from http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header : "Rather than allowing a space-separated list of origins, it is either a single origin or the string "null"" (first I've heard of "null" here btw)

Comment: The [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) clearly say that multiple values will cause the CORS algorithm to fails. So this isn't correct.

Comment: Also confirming this is incorrect. Using this to serve CSS to four domains, I receive an error in Chrome's log *"[...] header contains multiple values 'http://aaa.com, http://bbb.com', but only one is allowed"*. It does not matter if you define it as one header, or multiple, or using `add` vs. `set`. It just doesn't work.